# Dizzy with Excel VBA AND OR logical operators

Tags: vba, excel, logical-operators

I would like my procedure delete any row in which `column a (cA) is Fund ID 6347 OR 6349` **AND** has a basis point impact of `less than +/-100` **AND** `less than +/-50% price change`

The following code works to delete rows with: `either fund and a basis point impact +/- 100` but I don't believe it is working according to my intentions, as amid the extremely confusing parentheses in combination with the poor 2007 excel IDE interface, when I remove the `cells(i, cJ) >= -100)` code in the first line my test fails, leading me to believe that in some way my code works in part but on accident.

Does anyone understand the logic I am trying to code? Is there some web GUI were I can code excel VBA and see parenthesis highlighted for a better experience in these situations? Thank you

```
        For i = LR To 2 Step -1

                     If (Left(CStr(cells(i, cA)), 4) = "6347" And (cells(i, cJ) <= 100 And cells(i, cJ) >= -100)) Or _
                     (Left(CStr(cells(i, cA)), 4) = "6349" And (cells(i, cJ) <= 100) And cells(i, cJ) >= -100) Or _
                     Left(CStr(cells(i, cC)), 4) = "Trs " Or _
                     Mid(CStr(cells(i, cC)), 15, 8) = "bcomf1t " Or _
                     Mid(CStr(cells(i, cC)), 15, 7) = "bcomtr " Then
```

Comment: re: *'... in combination with the poor 2007 excel IDE interface'* It is the poor workman who blames his tools.

Comment: would splitting each "Or" statement in to its own "If" statement help you get the logic straightened out?

Comment: you code also checks for values in column `cC` to be either "Trs" or "bcomfit" or "bcomtr" in order to go ahead. Which is not what you declared at the beginning of your narrative. Who's right?

Comment: Your job would be much easier if you declared a few variables so you can remove all of those `CStr(Cells())` from the `If Then`

Comment: This could be simplified: `(cells(i, cJ) <= 100 And cells(i, cJ) >= -100))` to this: `Abs(cells(i, cJ).Value <= 100)`. But otherwise I would troubleshoot by breaking your `Or` statements in to their own `If` statements per sous2817 comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only bother about the "fund" and "impact" check, then go this way:

```
Dim okFund As Boolean, okImpact As Boolean

For I = LR To 2 Step -1

    okFund= Left(CStr(Cells(I, cA)), 4) = "6347" Or (Left(CStr(Cells(I, cA)), 4) = "6349"
    okImpact = Cells(I, cJ) <= 100 And Cells(I, cJ) >= -100

    If okFund And okImpact Then
```

Answer (score 4):

Pull the variables out of the spreadsheet *before* you build your if statement, then put them one on each line. This is much more efficient and makes it much, much easier to read.  Following your specification statement:

> I would like my procedure delete any row in which column a (cA) is
>   Fund ID 6347 OR 6349 AND has a basis point impact of less than +/-100
>   AND less than +/-50% price change

It would look like this (note that I'm guessing on what values come from where, and your code has additional conditions you don't specify):

```
Dim FundId As String
FundId = Left$(Cells(i, cA).Value, 4)
Dim BasisImpact As Long
BasisImpact = Cells(i, cJ).Value
Dim PriceChange As Long
PriceChange = Cells(i, whereever).Value

If (FundId = "6347" Or FundId = "6349") And _
   (BasisImpact >= -100 And BasisImpact <= 100) And _
   (PriceChange >= -50 And PriceChange <= 50) Then
```

As pointed out by @Jeeped in the comments, VBA will perform *all* of the tests in an `If` statement (it doesn't short circuit).  If this is in a performance critical part of your code or you have a huge data set, nesting the `If` statements and Worksheet accesses will give you better performance:

```
If FundId = "6347" Or FundId = "6349" Then
    Dim BasisImpact As Long
    BasisImpact = Cells(i, cJ).Value
    If BasisImpact >= -100 And BasisImpact <= 100 Then
        Dim PriceChange As Long
        PriceChange = Cells(i, whereever).Value
        If PriceChange >= -50 And PriceChange <= 50 Then
            'Do your thing
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Why process all conditions every time? Nesting each set of conditions might make the process easier to understand and the inner 'nests' will not get evaluated unless the outer ones have already matched. *Hint:* For best optimization, the *least likely* should be the outer conditions.e.g. if there were 7000 fund IDs and only two possible matches, then that would probably be the best outer condition.

Comment: Because...reasons?  The *real* reason is that the majority of my coding at work is in C#, and sometimes I forget that VBA doesn't short circuit.

Comment: :) Just a suggestion for optimization... not a disparagement.